# mssql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource error, not sure why

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

This is my first time with PHP and MSSQL.  I basically want to send name, email from a PHP form to a MSSQL db but I am getting the error in title.

My code is as follow

index.php

```
<title></title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form action="connection.php" name="frmAdd" method="post">  
<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th width="91"> <div align="center">Name</div></th>  
<th width="160"> <div align="center">Email</div></th>  
</tr>  
<tr>   

<td><input type="text" name="Name" size="20"></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="Email" size="20"></td>  

</tr>  
</table>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

and the connection.php

```
<?php

     $Name = $_POST['Name'];
     $Email= $_POST['Email'];


   $dbc = mssql_connect('localhost','**','**.','**')or            die('Error connecting to the SQL Server database.');


   $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.customers (customerName,customerEmail) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')GO";
   $result = mssql_query($dbc,$query)or die('Error querying MSSQL database');


   mssql_close($dbc);

?>
```

Comment: What's `GO` doing in `('$Name','$Email')GO";`? Remove it.

Comment: Remove the GO in the insert statement. Also tell us the exact error which you are getting

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because your query failed to execute. Remove `Go` from your query.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.customers (customerName,customerEmail) VALUES
('$Name','$Email')GO";
                   ^
```

and change it to

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.customers (customerName,customerEmail) VALUES 
('$Name','$Email')";
```